# Jupyter-lab see from which file the function was imported

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

While working in Jupyter I import from many files. How can I detect which jupyter file a function or variable comes from on the notebook?

For example;

```
%run file_1.ipynb
%run file_2.ipynb
```

```
my_amazing_function()
```

Is this function defined in file_1 or file_2? How can I see where this is defined?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import inspect
inspect.getabsfile(my_amazing_function)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
The program output when I try this 
'/tmp/ipykernel_35397/2764101994.py'
This does not give me information about the notebook from which the function was imported.

Comment: I would reccomend transforming your jupyters in .py as the fastest way to find out. However I don't work in jupyters, so I don't see how my answear doesn't work in your case. You are sure that my_amazing_function is declared in those notebooks and not imported?

Answer (score 0):

With the following snippet, I can find which jupyter file a function or variable is in.

I couldn't find a plugin that I can use in Jupyter-lab, for now this works for me

```
import glob
pattern = "./*.ipynb"
query = "def my_amazing_function"

files = []

for filepath in glob.iglob(pattern, recursive=True):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        s = file.read()
        if s.find(query) > -1:
            files.append(filepath)
if not files:
    print('No matching results')
else:
    print(f'Results for `{query}`')
    for f in files:
        print(f + '\n')`
```