# Script to Recursively Find Import Paths in Jupyter Notebook or Python Files

Tags: python, module, python-import, dependency-management

I'm relatively new to programming and have encountered a challenge with a Jupyter-lab environment I've inherited. The project contains a complex structure of folders, subfolders, and scripts without any documentation. My goal is to understand and re-run some models in a Jupyter notebook, which includes numerous imports from locally defined packages and modules scattered across various directories.

To streamline this process, I'm considering developing a script that can parse a notebook or Python file to recursively identify all import statements and their respective paths within the root directory. For example, if an import statement is the following: "from folder_a import module_a", I want to retrieve the path to module_a BUT also locate all the imports in module_a and their paths, so on and so forth until I get all the internal dependencies of this notebook.

My initial idea involves reading the file, splitting it by line, and extracting lines that begin with 'from' or 'import'. However, the diversity of import statement syntaxes (including aliases, submodules, and class attributes, which are not my focus) complicates the task significantly.

Before diving into this project, I wanted to ask if anyone is aware of an existing solution to this problem. Additionally, would it be beneficial to create such a script and share it on GitHub for others facing similar issues?

Any guidance or references to existing tools would be greatly appreciated.

Bests

Comment: you may want something like this: https://github.com/nbgallery/ipydeps, there is also some intel you can get from sys.modules and os.path.asbpath of its keys.

Comment: That package ipydps seems woefully ignorant of current best practices in order to overstate its utility. From the README: "Unlike `!pip install`, ipydeps makes sure that the packages get installed into the same Python environment that's executing your notebook's code cells. No more `!pip`, `!pip3`, `!pip -V` frustrations for you and your users." In 2019 the magic install commands, including a variation for `pip`, were added to IPython.Jupyter. Use of the magic commands is current best practice, see ....

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands. No one should be suggesting use of exclamation point in conjunction with install commands anymore. The magic install now even works with JupyterLite and Google Colab.

Comment: To find out what is getting imported there is `pipreqsnb`, see [here](https://medium.com/@ivalengy/pipreqsnb-pipreqs-with-jupyter-notebook-support-931dc3cf9330) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356319/8508004) for more about that. Watermark makes nice lists of what gets imported and so that may help, but I point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356319/8508004) some packages imported with `from X import Y` fail to get identified. Also, there is (was?) [pyflyby](https://labs.quansight.org/blog/2021/07/pyflyby-improving-efficiency-of-jupyter-interactive-sessions) that autoimports.

Comment: Then to get the path in the respective directory use `inspect`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/248862/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12154601/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72744477/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59378808/8508004).

Comment: I probably should also mention along the lines of seeing the dependencies, "`pipdeptree` to see a python project's dependency graph, but pip-tools (pip-compile) seems to do the same + document it in the requirements.txt file". That quote is from Bob Belderbos [here] (https://twitter.com/bbelderbos/status/1761021267740594374). He goes onto say with the new uv tool you can run it even faster.